# creating a connection string for a published product

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a product that connects to a database in SQL Server.  I have a connection string that I have been using in the design phase, and am now looking to produce an installation program.  My over riding assumption is that the people that are going to be using the product do not know anything about a connection string, so I am looking to keep this as simple as possible for the user.

I found one listing that shows how to query SQL Server as to which databases, tables, etc. are installed, but I have not found one on how to make the connection to SQL Server to make the query.

The connection strings I have seen are specific, I am looking for something more general.  Is the term I am looking for a connection string? I'm confused.

Comment: Can you tell for what? mybe [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) will help you

Comment: So your product connects to any database rather than one distributed with your application? Is it only Microsoft SQL Server or do you support other DBMS products?

Answer (score 0):

The product intent is to be a tool that interacts with an ACT database that imports customer information from a couple of tables and when a record is found imports the customer information into a word file to create a building contract.  Second phase will import customer information into a second SQL Server database so that the user can track the potential customers.  Right now I'm only working on the first phase, and the only database I am connecting to is an existing ACT database.  ACT database is done in SQL Server.  When a customer is installing the product ACT (should be) already installed.

In the process of installing this I also need to determine if ACT is installed in the first place.

I know the format for a connection string.  that's not the problem.  What I'm looking for is a way to query SQL Server and see what databases are installed.  This would be used in two places: 1) the installation program, and 2) in a utility program so that the user can change the connection string if the user finds out they connected to the wrong database.

Comment: IIRC, you can get the list of databases on a SQL Server via "select name from master.dbo.sysdatabases".

Answer (score 0):

I did get this portion of code working. The App.config file I edited is in another application that is not running when the utility form is running (or should not be running).  I also created a module that returns the config string and sets the config string.  On the utility form the current config string is displayed, with a button to change it.  This button starts with clearing the text box, then calling the form that steps the user through changing, and returns to the calling form.  Then I call the module that returns the config string that has been saved in the app.config file.  The problem I am having is that I can validate the config string has been changed, but it returns the original config string (prior to the change).  My assumption is that my utility program does a file lock, and it needs to be unlocked and refreshed.